# JSON.parse: unexpected end of data не пойму из-за чего

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'],$_POST['password'])){
   $a= $db->getRow('select Id_Users,Fam_Users,Name_Users,Otch_Users from Users WHERE    Logon_Users=?s AND Password_Users=?s',$_POST['login'],$_POST['password']);
}
if (empty($a)){
    $arg["error"]="Пара логин пароль не верны";
} else {
    $arg["error"]="0";
    $_SESSION['Id_Users']=$a['Id_Users'];
    $_SESSION['Fam_Users']=$a['Fam_Users'];
    $_SESSION['Name_Users']=$a['Name_Users'];
    $_SESSION['Otch_Users']=$a['Otch_Users'];
}
echo json_encode($arg,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Вот так делаю запрос:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var send = document.getElementById("avtoriz");
var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
var resp = document.getElementById("resp");
var form = new FormData();
send.onclick= function() {
form.append("login",document.getElementById("login").value);
form.append("password",document.getElementById("password").value);
    xhr.open("post","user_iden/autorization",true);
  xhr.send(form);
  resp.innerHTML=xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
};
xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
  if (xhr.status != 200) {
  show(resp);
  resp.innerHTML=xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText 
  } else {
  var respons = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText, function(key, value) {
  if (key == 'error') return new String(value);
  return value;
});

     if (respons.error=='0')
     {
      location.reload();
     } else {
     resp.innerHTML=respons.error;
     show(resp);
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

В принципе все работает как надо, но вот не пойму почему ошибку выдает

Comment: Ну вы посмотрели что возвращается от сервера?

Comment: @u_mulder Да, например вот: {"error":"Пара логин пароль не верны"}

Comment: Код тут не нужен, нужен именно JSON. То, что Вы привели (`{"error":"Пара логин пароль не верны"}`) вполне корректно парится. И проверяйте на ошибки тут: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял откуда ноги растут этой ошибки, и так xhr.status возвращает 200 до загрузки тела запроса и получается JSON.parse вызывается аж 2 раза, при пустом и когда загружено тело запроса, вот верный кусок:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var send = document.getElementById("avtoriz");
var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
var resp = document.getElementById("resp");
var form = new FormData();
send.onclick= function() {
form.append("login",document.getElementById("login").value);
form.append("password",document.getElementById("password").value);
    xhr.open("post","user_iden/autorization",true);
  xhr.send(form);
};
xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
if (xhr.readyState==4){
  if (xhr.status != 200) {
  show(resp);
  resp.innerHTML=xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText 
  } else {
  var respons = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText, function(key, value) {
  if (key == 'error') return new String(value);
  return value;
});

     if (respons.error=="Нет ошибки")
     {
      location.reload();
     } else {
     resp.innerHTML=respons.error;
     show(resp);
     }
  }
}
};
</script>
```